# How can i avoid rate limit problems in this case?

Tags: python, web-scraping, rate-limiting

I'm new in scrapping and I'm figthing with Rate Limit.

The data that I am trying to scrape is found in web pages that share a url except for a part that I will call CODE.

The problem that I found is that having the ammount of different codes i have I can only download around the first one hundred before being limited by the web.

```
for code in codes:
    url=url_partido.format(code)
    data=requests.get(url)
    with open("nbadata/games22/{}.html".format(code),"w+") as f:
        f.write(data.text)
```

This way Im extracting first Data, the problem is that I have around 1000 different codes and I get blocked around 100.

I read about different ways of dodge rate limit and one was changing the header to make the server think we come from a navigator:

```
data = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
for code in codes:
    url=url_partido.format(code)
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36'}
    
    data = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    with open("nbadata/games22/{}.html".format(code),"w+") as f:
        f.write(data.text)
```

Fail, same problem. Also tried to add timesleep(1) to reduce the ammount of demands.

The most useful thing I read was that changing between different servers will be the final answer. I know there are free servers or premium ones. I found some of them and I tried this but IT ALSO FAIL.

```
servers = ['95.216.194.46:1081', '45.174.87.18:999', ' 45.6.4.60:8080']
for code in codes:
    for server in servers:
        try:
            url = url_partido.format(code).replace('{server}', server)
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36'}
            data = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
            with open("nbadata/games22/{}.html".format(code),"w+") as f:
                f.write(data.text)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error {url}: {e}")
            continue
```

Can you please give me some ideas or tell me what is wrong?

THANK YOU!

Comment: what about `time.sleep(10)` at the end of your loop or if you wanted to get a little more advanced, `urllib3.util.retry.Retry` with a `backoff_factor`?

Comment: It would also probably be helpful to know the exact error you see?

Comment: Thank you @JonSG, I'm trying again with time.sleep. I dont know which error show because code starts working but the files that it creates shows only this: 
Error 1015
Ray ID: 795e2d551d822fbb • 2023-02-07 18:27:00 UTC
You are being rate limited
What happened?

The owner of this website (www.basketball-reference.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.

Comment: Sometimes an api will return a more helpful message like "banned until xxxx utc" with a formal 429 error.  That might help you figure out how to move forward.  I have found that some facebook apis like upto a minute between request to keep them happy

Answer (score 3):

You're rotating proxies for this which is the right way to go, but I've never had much luck with free proxies myself. You could try some from  https://geonode.com/free-proxy-list and sort by Uptime and Speed, but honestly, I'd just go for a premium residential proxy.

**Reference:**

[What Are Residential Proxies And Why Do You Need Them?](https://get.brightdata.com/bd-what-is-a-residential-proxy)